# Select nodes that 1) precede a given node but 2) are also descendants of another given node

Tags: xpath

Say I have the following XML:

```
<body>
    <div id="global-header">
        header
    </div>

    <div class="a">
        <h3>some title</h3>
        
        <p>text 1</p>
        
        <p>text 2</p>
        
        <p>text 3</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

I want to

1. find any `<p>` node whose value is "text 2", and then
2. find all the nodes that precede this particular `<p>` but are also descendants of the `<div class='a'>` node.

The desired output should look like:

```
<h3>some title</h3>

<p>text 1</p>
```

The caveat is that the preceding nodes may contain arbitrary node type, not only `<h3>` and `<p>`, as in the above case.

My first try:

```
.//p[text()="text 2"]/preceding::*
```

Unfortunately, this will also select `<div id="global-header">`, which is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preceding-sibling` to select nodes that are children of the same parent instead of `preceding`:

```
.//p[text()="text 2"]/preceding-sibling::*
```

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question. But I have a follow-up question, to comply with the SO rules I create [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419408/select-text-that-1-precede-a-given-node-but-2-are-also-descendants-of-anot), would you please answer it?