# Select `text()` that 1) precede a given node but 2) are also descendants of another given node

Tags: xpath

This is a follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384505/select-nodes-that-1-precede-a-given-node-but-2-are-also-descendants-of-another/64386020#64386020), but unfortunately the answer from that question doesn't apply.

Say I have the following XML:

```
<body>
    <div id="global-header">
        header
    </div>

    <div id="a">
        <h3>some title</h3>
        
        <p>text 1 
            <b>bold</b>
        </p>
        
        <div>
            <p>abc</p>
            <p>text 2</p>
            <p>def</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

I want to

1. find the `<p>` node whose value is "text 2" (assume we only have exactly one such `<p>`), and then
2. find all the nodes that precede this particular `<p>` but are also descendants of the `<div id='a'>` node(you can use something like `[@id='a']` to locate it), and finally
3. extract `text()` from step 2.

The desired output should look like:

```
some title
text 1
bold
abc
```

The caveat is that

1. the preceding nodes may contain arbitrary node type, not only `<h3>` and `<p>`.
2. the `<p>text 2</p>` node may be embeded **arbitrarly** deep in the tree, hence xpath like `.//p[text()="text 2"]/preceding-sibling::*` would only extract `<p>abc</p>` and leave out others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XPath expression:

```
//p[.='text 2']/preceding::text()[ancestor::div[@id='a']]
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that the `text()` nodes may not be clearly separated, but rather merged for the sub-elements. To separate them, you'd need some kind of for-loop.